# jQuery working in Firefox, Chrome, Opera but not IE 11

Tags: javascript, jquery, internet-explorer

I can't figure out why. When I run IE 11 in compatibility mode the jQuery works great. Otherwise it doesn't even load my jQuery. I have tons of `console.log` in my code to debug and none of those display in the console. I'm not getting errors in the console, but I do on my server which is Ruby code. The errors are below:

```
I, [2017-06-01T15:16:46.790492 #22201]  INFO -- : Started GET "/my_file.js" 

I, [2017-06-01T15:16:46.795990 #22201]  INFO -- : Processing by ScriptsController#my_action as HTML
I, [2017-06-01T15:16:46.797140 #22201]  INFO -- : Completed 406 Not Acceptable in 0ms (ActiveRecord: 0.0ms)
F, [2017-06-01T15:16:46.798323 #22201] FATAL -- : 
ActionController::UnknownFormat (ActionController::UnknownFormat):
  app/controllers/scripts_controller.rb:5:in `my_action'
```

All the other browsers correctly process my jQuery as js while IE processes it as HTML. No idea why.

This is how the script is included on the site:

```
<script language="javascript" type="application/javascript" src="https://my_server.com/my_file.js"></script>
```

I believe its some sort of compatibility issue, just no idea how to fix?

EDIT:
There is a difference in the header between IE and the other browsers:
In IE 11 the differences are in the following:

```
"HTTP_ACCEPT"=>"application/javascript, */*;q=0.8", 
"HTTP_ACCEPT_LANGUAGE"=>"en-US", 
"HTTP_ACCEPT_ENCODING"=>"gzip, deflate",
```

While firefox looks like this:

```
"HTTP_ACCEPT"=>"*/*", 
"HTTP_ACCEPT_ENCODING"=>"gzip, deflate, sdch, br",
"HTTP_ACCEPT_LANGUAGE"=>"en-US,en;q=0.8"
```

I wonder if that might be it?

Comment: `<script type="text/javascript" src="https://my_server.com/my_file.js"></script>` Note that attribute type has been depriciated

Comment: Thanks.. yea I've read seemingly 10 different versions of "type" and tried them all with no luck..

Comment: What this question has to do with [tag:ruby] and [tag:ruby-on-rails]?!

Comment: The server that replies with the 406 error is running Ruby, as stated in the OP